# Django ModelForm Wizard - How to create the database object?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I have a Model enought big to be cut in 3 Forms.
I wanted to use FormWizzard to do that and I am wondering, **how to save the information from the form to the database?**

Everything is from the same model.

Do you have any idea of how to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no clear/direct way to do this.

However, you could *hack around* to achieve the desired functionality;

I can think of doing it this way:

- Create n (the number of pages of wizard you want) modelforms of the same model, but with different `fields` and `extra` on the meta class.
- Override the save of the first (n-1) model forms to just `pass`
- Override the save of the last form to create a new model with the data from all `n` wizard forms, and call super.

However, as I said, this is really a "hack" and it may be *clearer* and *pythonic* to use different views, forms and the session.